# How to get path of a hidden sheet in VBA project?

Tags: excel, vba

As I am trying to convert an xml response to recordset via hidden sheet. I am saving that sheet in my project itself but while accessing that to convert it to recordset, I need its path. Currently my path is system/user dependent but I want a generic path so that we need not to hardcode it each time we run the project in a different system. As my hidden sheet is being stored in my current work environment where my project is running, is it possible to get it without providing the full path?
**Current situation:Source=C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\Main Interface\MyProject.xlsm;"
Desired situation: Source=(something independent of system)\MyProject.xlsm OR something like it.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ActiveWorkbook.path` to get the path relative where your workbook is. You could also append & "/foldername" to get it from subfolders.

Comment: I might recommend `ThisWorkbook` instead

Answer (score 1):

After trying few things this one I found most suitable to my requirements.

"Source= " & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";".